# Generalization of javascript callbacks functions

Tags: javascript, windows-8, callback

I would like to create about 10 XML HTTP requests as below. I would like to use the value of `i` for the first "children" reference, but as `i` changes before the callback is executed, the value of `i` mismatches the url taken in "results" tab. How can I generalize this?

```
var i = 1;
WinJS.xhr({
    url: root.results[i].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[1].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
});

i = 2;

WinJS.xhr({
    url: root.results[i].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[2].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
});
```

Comment: That's a common scoping issue in Javascript. It is usually solved by introducing a new scope layer, so does your actual code implement a loop instead of duplicating calls to `xhr()`? Also, is your ultimate goal to chain the requests or to perform all of them in parallel?

Comment: Does i depend on which order the requests where send or on the order that they are done?

Comment: `i` is not used in the callback, only in the assignment to `.url` which will happen immediately. So I don't see where you're suffering from async behavior.

Comment: @Yoshi, the questioner actually wants to use `i` in the callback as well.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah, that didn't get through to me ;)

Comment: The queries can be executed in parallel. I was loading profile pictures from Twitter. Thank to StackOverflow I just submitted my app :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the typical way is to use an extra function (immediately executed) to *capture* the current value of your loop variable, e.g.:

```
var i = 1;

WinJS.xhr({
    url: root.results[i].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (inner_i) {
  // return the actual callback
  return function (result) {
    // use `inner_i` as needed
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[1].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
      oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
  };
}(i)); // <= pass outer `i`
```

Answer (score 1):

IN general you can do two things;

1. use an extra function
2. use an extra variable

In the argumentobject `{}` from `WinJS.xhr` there is no scope to copy the variable to, so I'll go with option 1:

```
var i = 1;
WinJS.xhr({
    url: root.results[ return function(i) { return i; }(i) ].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[1].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
});

i = 2;

WinJS.xhr({
    url: root.results[ return function(i) { return i; }(i) ].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[2].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
});
```

Update: extra variable:

```
var i = 1;
WinJS.xhr({
    copiedVar: i,
    url: root.results[ copiedVar ].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[1].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
});

i = 2;

WinJS.xhr({
    copiedVar: i,
    url: root.results[ copiedVar ].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[2].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this helps? I don't think it's an issue of scoping at all it's an issue of asynchronous calls.

Comment: When you create the argument object, the extra function will be invoked with `i` as a parameter, and the function will instantly return the value, even when the value of i changes after the object creation.

Comment: Right gotcha, yeah that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the value of i inside the callback function. That way, it won't increment until after it's used.

```
var i = 1;

WinJS.xhr({
    url: root.results[i].profile_image_url_https,
    responseType: 'blob'
}).done(function (result) {
    var imgTag = theDiv.children[1].children[0];
    var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(result.response, {
        oneTimeOnly: true
    });
    imgTag.src = imageBlob; //tempLocalUrl;

    i++;

});
```

Comment: But depending on the order of 'done', this might mess things up. Actually the question is whether or not it's about the order "done" or the order "send" (I assumed send)

Comment: I just noticed that sorry! I can't see where you use i again though so maybe you could explain further about how it doesn't match "the url taken in results tab"?

Comment: Hang on a minute... I can't actually see why you need a variable at all. Can't you just hard code the values?

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing the value in the callback might for this case. But a generic way of solving this scope issue is to use javascript closures. Please take a look at http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Answer (score -1):

This is a great case where I would consider an approach using joined promises, that are nested:

```
var operations = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    operations.push(WinJS.join({
        myValue: i,
        xhr: WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://foo" }),
    }).then(function(data) {
       var yourValue = data.myValue;
       var xhrResponse = data.xhr;

       // Your processing you had before
    }));
 }

 WinJS.Promise.join(operations).done(function(operations) {
     // Done
 });
```

This gives you the opportunity to keep things isolated & contained.